# Is it possible to set the context to an outside variable inside a loop

Tags: dust.js

I would like to get content from the below JSON as "Discover xx76" and "Visa xx73" etc.

```
{
    "challengeMap": {
        "CARD": {
            "verifier": [
                {
                    "value": "Discover",
                    "key": "0"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Visa",
                    "key": "1"
                }
            ],
            "additionalVerifier": [
                {
                    "value": "xx76",
                    "key": "0"
                },
                {
                    "value": "xx73",
                    "key": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to iterate through the VERIFIER array... but from there I can't access the "additionalVerifier" array. Is there any chances (or) do I need to change the JSON structure?

```
{#challengeMap.CARD.verifier}
  {value} - {challengeMap.CARD.additionalVerifier[$idx].value}
{/challengeMap.CARD.verifier}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your context is the CARD.verifier and you're trying to access a parent level other context -> CARD.additionalVerifier

you can :
1) change the JSON structure.
2) try the following:

```
    {#challengeMap.CARD.verifier card=challengeMap.CARD}
      {value} - {additionalVerifier[{@idx}].value}
    {/challengeMap.CARD.verifier}


    or 

    {#challengeMap.CARD.verifier:challengeMap.CARD}
      {value} - {additionalVerifier{@idx}].value}
    {/challengeMap.CARD.verifier}
```

[Dust Tutorial with Examples.](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial)

you can add helpers and print the context at that stage..

{@contextDump key="current" to="console/}

then check the browser console / node.js console...

Comment: thanks for your valuable time for the input. Do you mean to say that change the JSON structure and try the above code?. Or the above code works for the JSON structure which I provided in the post. Please confirm